# Select statement Data return Slow start from particular month

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I running a `Select` Statement with some `join` statement and did to add on the indexing to increasing the speed of searching the result, but when I start to select particular `month`(Only a month Record) the data returning become very slow (more than 5 min supposedly those previous month records just need 1-3 second to return all) and I don't know what is going on, FYI few of the previous month record is more than the particular month (Only a month Record) that I selected, if anyone used to encounter such issue please give some advise thanks

*Methods that I have tried to do to improve the performance but it is not helping*

1.try to close some unnecessary join statement

2.Change the method of join(From Left Join to Inner Join)

3.replace the join whole table to the sub query(Select few columns which is needed)

Comment: We can't help you without seeing the query.

Comment: how can anyone help you if you dont show us the query and the actual execution plan ? Also, replacing a join by a subquery is most of the time worse for performance